# Using GeShi with Zotonic CMS

Tags: php, erlang, syntax-highlighting, geshi, zotonic

Is it possible to use the  [GeShi syntax highlighter](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) (written with PHP) with Zotonic CMS (written with erlang) ?

**Does a specific module exist or is it necessary to make some modification with erlang ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible - unless you write a module that executes an external script, passing the source code to highlight, and the external script is a PHP script that does the highlighting.